# the pre-init function

Tags: c#, javascript

I am working in a specific task. 
I have three master pages with three different stylesheet,

I have a javascript function that can detect what the user is using for example window,mobile or iPad...

When the page size for example is less than 700 I want to set master page 1 foe example and when the page size is greater than 700 I want to set it as master page 2 on the pre-init function of the server side.

Would anyone have a clue to solve my problem?

Comment: but how would i accept an answer i don't know how :S

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript to detect the screen size, Use the HttpHeader [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to detect the client device, change the master page at the server side.

You can access the user agent header sent by the client in the Pre-Init function of the ASP.NET pipeline, you can also access it within a controller, or a page object (depending on what server side framework u are using)

```
string S = HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
```

It will give you result like :

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"
```

if client is using PC, if he using IPhone

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
```

For android look [here](http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/)

Comment: can i call this User-Agent function in the pre-inti function ?

Comment: yes i am using .Net C# . is their a way to know the device of the user like if he is using a mobile despite what is the mobile ( nokia samsung..) i can know that he is using a mobile and not something else

Comment: For server programming all you need to know about the device, is in the user agent. Look into the `Request.Browser` property for anything more that you may need. Anything even more specific will have to be hacks with javascript.